# sorting unique values in an array with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to write a `method` in Ruby which takes an array of items and returns the array without any duplicates. Without using Ruby’s `uniq` method?

So, the output of this array `[1,5,"frog", 2,1,3,"frog"]` will be `[1,5,"frog",2,3]`

Comment: `select` block should use `{...}` to start with - please post code that is at least compiling successfully

Comment: _Sidenote_: `i != i` returns `false` _always_.

Comment: And you're not doing any sorting.

Comment: And `to_a` is redundant.

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output? What does it mean to "sort the unique values"?

Comment: @m-alow I've rolled back your edit, because the wrong bracket are causing the "unexpected end-of-input" error.

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope that helps understand better.

Comment: @WandMaker What made it -5 down vote to this question?

Comment: @DebRaj My guess is that code sample given in first version was not working one, also it did not indicate that you have made honest attempt at solving the issue and asked the question only when you got really stuck.  Have look at [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference.

Comment: @WandMaker I tried to paste code to describe the problem and realized the code is totally misleading so later tried to edit the question as per their suggestion.

Comment: @DebRaj  Don't worry, be more thorough in future.  Down votes are part and parcel of SO, and are good triggers for us to improve how to ask and answer.

Comment: @WandMaker Is it good to ask another question in comments? Because I can't ask new question as it's been blocked for my account for this down vote.

Comment: @DebRaj You can seek clarifications for an answer by posting comments to that answer so that author of that answer can clarity it and/or update the answer further.  If it is entirely new question, then, you can post it as new question.

Comment: Is there a way I can improve the quality of the questions.? Stuck on another issue and during this down vote can't ask new question. Thanks guys.

Comment: @WandMaker Can you help me with a simple code. I know it's not related to this question is already down voted and for same reason I can't able to ask new question.

Comment: @DebRaj Feel free to ask a new question, as long as it is well written, you should get answer from SO users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an unexpected end-of-input because you are using parenthesis instead of braces to denote the block. Try:

```
my_array.to_a.select{ |i| i != i }
```

But even this isn't quite what you'd expect. Here is an alternative:

```
my_array.group_by{|item| item}.keys
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You missed the sort part.

Comment: Seems like he is trying to implement it

Comment: This is my final code with your code reference and it works perfect:

`def uniques(my_array)
 my_array.group_by{|item| item}.keys
end
puts uniques([1,5,"frog", 2,1,3,"frog"])`

Comment: Hey buddy, it's great to hear back from you. I'm glad to hear I was able to help you out. Good luck with all your future endeavors! Take care

Comment: Wondering what made it -5 down vote to this question

Answer (score 1):

```
 my_array = [1, 5, "frog", 2, 1, 3, "frog"]
 uniques = []

 my_array.each do |x|
   uniques << x unless uniques.include?(x)
 end
```

This iterates through `my_array` and only pushes to `uniques` elements it doesn't include.

Comment: You missed the sort part.

Comment: How the result of this differs from `Array#uniq`? Besides that, consider using `Array#inject` for this purpose, instead of phpish appending to preexisting array.

Comment: BTW, you can use `unless` instead of `if !`